# Is there any difference between "immune from" and "immune against" in the following sentence?

Tags: differences, prepositions

"His position as president renders him immune ..... criticism."

Any subtle difference concerning the viability and efficacy of criticism, according to the preposition used?

[image]

The Ngram shows that "immune against" has always been unusual. Still, we can find it now and then.

Comment: What audience would have trouble discerning the meaning if to/from are interchanged?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's a region thing, but I have never heard *immune* used with the preposition *against*.  I always hear *immune* with either *to* or *from*.

In that case, both *immune to* and *immune from* have the same connotation, though I hear *immune to* more often.

A quick search on Google Ngram confirms my thoughts:

[image]

Comment: I've added a more specific Ngram.

Answer (score 3):

A doctor, who was also an English grammarian and wanted to be entirely clear, would likely prefer to say *only* that you are ***immune to*** the pathogen he immunized you with.

Saying *immune from* has the possibility of implying that you are immune *because of* the pathogen. Though it is a weakened form of the pathogen that made you this way, it is still not those poor little, long dead guys that the doctor is trying to convey you are *immune to*, it is *all the other,* (and full-strength) pathogens of that particular disease that you are indeed immune to. In fact this very doctor might have a situational need to say that you are indeed *immune from* those poor little, long dead guys that he injected into you, hence another reason to be strict.

This, of course, is a parsing of the literal meaning, but the idiomatic use is derived directly from  the literal and does not have currency on its own, without its etymological origins in the medicinal use.

Now, *immune against* is just wrong because of either a seeming redundancy or plain misuse.

In the case of calling it redundancy I mean to point out that the quality of being *against* something is built into the word *immune*, so the *against* in, *immune against,* is superfluous, somehow.

In the case for just calling it misuse I think it is odd to be *against* something that, in actuality, cannot harm you whatsoever (as a result of the ostensible *immunity* to it).

*Immune to* strikes as being the only reasonable usage for your example, assuming that the statement means to say that the president cannot be harmed by criticism because of his position.

I'd leave open the possibility that, like in the doctor's example, that a person could become *immune from* criticism. For example:

"Her life growing up with four brothers left her immune from criticism, hence the booing from the audience did not faze her."

Comment: How come I'm immute *to* something because I've been immunized *against* it?

Comment: Well, "I've been immunized against" is stepping into all new territory with the change of tense. It doesn't sound as awkward as "immune against." But I still feel it is redundant as the _immunity_ itself contains the "against"-ness. "To" seems enough. The "against" is already there. But again, you're example in that tense doesn't quite raise the eyebrow so readily as "immune against" does, especially when used idiomatically. @bof

Comment: And it's certainly okay colloquially. The point is made, the idea conveyed - I'm no grammarian cop. But if we're gonna parse, well then, thems there the facts! "Immune" meaning _not "mune"_ (which gets dubious etymologically) distinctly has the "not" right there in the word and seems to conflict (in redundancy) with "against."

Comment: @bof and Jack Roy.   F.T.Wood says the following: "If we say that **a person's position** renders him immune from criticism , we mean that it prevents any criticism of him being expressed; if we say that that his position renders him immune against criticism , we mean that criticism of him is made, but it is ineffective because he is protected by his position.  What do you say?

Comment: Well, it strikes me as: that'd be nice if there was a delineation along those lines. To be able to express the difference between immune by position to there being any assaulting agent whatsoever vs. being immune by having the status of inoculation to the outside force - and there might be some way that could be parsed from the old, original meaning of "not municipal" (if we can even be sure that's the etymological source, as it might be "not mutable/changeable) that could justify that... (though I can't see it)...

Comment: I would contend though, that the modern usage is inextricably associated with the medical usage (and the attempt on Wood's part to parse it so has no precedent that I know of) and adhering to its implications that can be understood by the vast majority of people who understand this etymology (being immunized themselves, having children who need immunization, etc.) has the most value/currency. Also, there's some problem with Wood's attempt to deem "_immuning_ " as rendering all pathogens null and void in the 1st example, as opposed to the natural association of rendering a known Pathogen inert.

Comment: Ultimately context always matters. But in every current context I stand by my post, that instead of a mess of speculation we have some very useful clarity if we want it. I also stand by the belief that: if it's understood, it's right. But Wood is trying to make a further potential clarity that I can't see, and more importantly, I don't think most people would (no pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that from, to and against are all valid usages and depend on the way in which immunity occurs. Something or someone could be naturally immune **from** something, but if it weren't it could be made immune **to** it by being immunized (classical spelling!) **against** it.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Sources and/or citations are expected to support answers, and opinions are usually restricted to comments section. When you have enough reputation, you will be able to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

Immunity is about how well we can face an oncoming threat. Naturally our defence "army" of organisms will directly attack and repel the invaders. When we attack we face and move towards the threat. The logical preposition to use is "to". Immune from implies running away and hiding, being in a safe, isolated place. Maybe a better word would be safe or isolated "from".